# Объяснение работы метода .slice()

Tags: javascript

Есть функция

```
const capitalize = name => name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в результате в заглавной букве присоединяется всё оставшееся слово, а не только второй символ? `name.slice(1)`

Comment: потому что, если указан только один аргумент, метод [.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) возвращает часть строки от заданного индекса до конца строки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [String.prototype.slice(start, end)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), который вы вызываете в своей стрелочной функции, ожидает два входных параметра, оба приводятся к числу. Если одного из них не хватает, то есть метод был вызван как `name.slice(1)`, то в качестве второго параметра принимается вся длина строки `name.length`. Если же и первый аргумент отсутствует `name.slice()`, то считается, что он равен нулю.

Дальше этот метод уже работает с полученными данными, т.е. возвращает часть исходной строки начиная от индекса с номером start включительно, до *символа*<sup>*</sup> с индексом end, не учитывая его. Отрицательные индексы считаются от конца строки, таким образом −1 означает последний *символ* в данной строке.

Вот примеры:

```
var name = "Мастер"
name.slice(1, 4)                       // "аст"
name.slice(3) == name.slice(3, 6)      // "тер"
name.slice(3, -1) == name.slice(3, 5)  // "те"
name.slice(-2) == name.slice(-2, 6)    // "ер"
```

<sub>* Здесь имеется ввиду code point.</sub>